# Interpolation with analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

For $i \in \mathbb N$, Let $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb C$ with the $x_i$ distinct and having no limit point in $\mathbb C$.  Is it true that there is an entire function $f$ such that $f(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i$?  If the answer is no, are there any known conditions such that the answer becomes yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. You did not ask for a proof, so I'll just give you a reference: This is an exercise in Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*, chapter 5, section 2.3 (Series and Product Developments -> Partial Fractions and Factorization -> Canonical Products). In there you can find some context for a proof and a big hint.

Comment: It's also theorem 15.13 in Big Rudin.